# Draw random number using Poisson distribution in Python

Tags: python, random

I am trying to mimic a chance encounter and I'm not sure how to do this. I would like to use a poisson distribution, but am open to other suggestions.

The idea is this: there is a central place where you can meet people. If there are 10 (the minimum) people at this place, the chance is 100% you will meet a specific person (e.g., chance = 1). If there are 6000 (the maximum) people at this place, the chance you will meet everyone is 3.5% you will meet a specific person (e.g. Chance = 0.035). How can I implement this using Python?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Read the next-to-last sentence aloud.  Also, two data points are too few to infer a Poisson distribution.  And without talking about lambda, it's impossible to derive the the shape of the distribution.  Finally, events in Poisson are independent.  I doubt in a pool of 10 people you could make that assumption.  Go back and do your math first.

Comment: The Poisson distribution is not the correct distribution, unless you are trying to *count* the number of chance encounters that happen. Also this is not a programming question, this is a probability/stats question. In my opinion it belongs on https://stats.stackexchange.com instead. I encourage you to clarify your wording and ask again on that site instead of this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure if you can do Poisson distribution without μ.

This function will return a chance based on n, which is the number of people, and the given maximum and minimum values. In this calculation, the probability will be halved for each 1 point increase in the normalized value up to a certain point which is log(0.035)/log(0.5) or about 4.83650 because 0.5 ** 4.83650 ≈ 0.035. Meaning whenever n = maximum, the probability will be 0.035 and whenever n = minimum, the probability will be 1.

```py
import math
def chance(n): # n is the number of people
    maximum = 6000
    minimum = 10
    normalized = ((n - minimum) / (maximum - minimum)) * (math.log(0.035) / math.log(0.5))
    probability = 0.5 ** normalized
    return probability
```